NestJS App Using whatsapp-web.js Crashes After a Few Days and Stops Accepting Requests
I'm working on a NestJS project that uses the whatsapp-web.js library. After running for a few days, my application crashes, and my controllers stop accepting any requests. Additionally, my cron job stop working. Everything seems normal in the logs, and there are no explicit error messages. However, restarting the app temporarily resolves the issue.
Here is my main.ts file:
import { ValidationPipe, VersioningType } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { json, urlencoded } from 'express';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { API_KEY_TOKEN_HEADER, VALIDATION_PIPE_OPTIONS } from './shared/constants/common';
import { WhatsAppClientsManager } from './whatsapp/whatsapp-manager/whatsapp-clients-manager';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableVersioning({
    type: VersioningType.URI,
  });

  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe(VALIDATION_PIPE_OPTIONS));
  app.use(json({ limit: process.env.REQUEST_SIZE_LIMIT }));
  app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: process.env.REQUEST_SIZE_LIMIT }));
  app.enableCors();

  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('WhatsApp Api')
    .setDescription('WhatsApp Api description')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addApiKey({
      name: API_KEY_TOKEN_HEADER,
      type: 'apiKey',
      in: "header"
    }, API_KEY_TOKEN_HEADER)
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('swagger', app, document);
  app.enableCors();
await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}

process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.error('uncaughtException:', err);
 });

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);
 });

bootstrap();

Additional details:
NestJS version: v10.3.10
whatsapp-web.js version: v1.23.1-alpha.5
Node.js version: v21.7.2

What could be causing my application to crash after running for a few days?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Smells like a memory leak.

@LexW. You might be right, but when I remote into the server, the RAM usage is only at 50% free.

Could it be that there is a memory limit for individual processes?

your right, thanks

from the code that you provided, I do not see anything wrong yet.
May I know how do you run your app? Can you check your server CPU/memory usage ? Does your app connected to any 3rd party resources ?

I am running the application as a Windows service. Unfortunately, due to the intermittent nature of the issues, I frequently lack sufficient information to effectively diagnose and resolve the problem.

I think, one thing you can try is run the app without the cron job and see if it stops, if it is not, then it must be the cron

You should probably not post a question as an answer. If you require further information, please use comments instead.

@Guido, dev597 has only 1 reputation, he cannot (yet) post comments.
